# Serialization of big objects

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization, istringstream

I'm working with Boost::Serialization library in C++.
When I want to restore the object, I use the code below:

```
// ostr is of type std::ostringstream

std::vector<Certificate *> newCRL;
{
    std::istringstream ifs(ostr.str());
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> newCRL;
}
```

If the ostr is short in length, I can successfully restore my original object, but the
problem I have is with long ostr. If ostr is big, exception below is thrown in run-time:

```
std::length_error: basic_string::resize
```

I think `std::istringstream ifs(ostr.str());` is the source of this exception.
Is there any work around on this, that I can use to reconstruct big objects?

Comment: Why not use a `std::stringstream` rather than having separate `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream`s?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for this function to use `stringstream`s at all?  Avoid using them as a buffer if you can, since they can take very large amounts of memory.  Read directly from the original stream where you can.

Comment: @ildjarn: you are right! I will change my code, but the exception still exist!

Comment: @MooingDuck: text_iarchive takes an istream as input argument. I will change the type of ostr to stringstream and fed it into the text_iarchive, as ildjam said.

Comment: @ManiAmoozadeh: No, I mean, why do you have an `ostr` to begin with?  Is it absolutely necessary?

Comment: @MooingDuck: aha. I have a very long string and I decided to store it in ostr with type ostringstream! I can use other structures! ostringstream was the first option came to my mind to store my long string! and then I can fed it easilly to text_iarchive!

Comment: @osgx: at least 600 characters, but it can be much more (around 6000)

Comment: Doubtful the string size is the problem. Much more likely the issue is with the serialized content.